# What are ExternalLanguage cells good for?

Tags: python, external-calls, external-language-cell

You can type `>` at the beginning of a cell (or right click and choose "insert new cell" - "ExternalLanguage") and then you can choose the language - say "Python".

Then you can type in the cell `2+2` and you get output `4` generated by Python.
But what is a practical usage of this? How can I store this output in some variable that can Mathematica handle? Because when I type `var=2+2` in Python's cell and evaluate. Then type `var` in ordinary Mathematica cell I got `var` with no value assigned to it.

On the other hand you can do it easily like:

```
var=ExternalEvaluate["Python","2+2"]
var^2
(* 4 *)
(* 16 *)
```

So the code from Python has practical usage as a variable `var` in Mathematica.

But I can not see any practical usage of the ExternalLanguage cell.

**So my question is what are ExternalLanguage cells good for?**

Comment: Evaluating "2+2" in python is not helpful.  Running that external package that does that cool thing you need which someone wrote in python is very helpful.

Comment: That was not my question. I am asking how ExternalLanguage cells are helpful in Mathematica. What is advantage of running python in Mathematica cell than running in outside of it.

Comment: I agree with you that it would've been more useful had there been a syntax within the external cell, that would allow one to e.g. assign the result of cell's evaluation to some variable in WL, and likewise to import values of some WL's variables into external language session. Leaving that aside, the convenience of external language cells is that you can write external language code in a more visually pleasant way, without stringification at least. One can use the `%` to use the output of external cells in the WL cells that follow, forming a more visually pleasant hybrid language workflow.

Comment: When you evaluate the first Python cell in your notebook, a Python session is started which you can access in the usual way. For example, I tend to write a python cell in the beginning of my notebook that does all the `import`s and then I run `python = First@ExternalSessions[]`. Now I can access all the Python expressions via `ExternalEvaluate[python, "<your python expression>"]`.